# Changing computer name of clients and servers

Tags: windows

I recently joined another unit of my company, being in charge of the company's IT infrastructure, I need to rename all clients and servers using a standard naming convention.

No big thing, I'm done renaming all clients. But I'm thinking that renaming the servers (esp. the DC which happens to be the DNS server also) might cause some harm and break existing settings or configurations.

Is it ok to continue with renaming the servers? Are there things I should take note of? What should I do?

Comment: What server are you using (2003, 2008 etc)? By renaming, do you want to change the way the *domain controller* appears in AD or something else? e.g. - [rename domain controller in server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782761%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: The DC is a 2003 R2 and other which is a mirror DC and serves other purposes runs on 2008R2

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian, the answers below are ok for me. The reference you made was a good one too

Answer (score 0):

Renaming servers, is risky business, not because of active directory. Though you have to follow the steps MS outlines in how to rename a domain controller.  Though I prefer setting up a new DC, waiting for it to replicate, then decommissioning or downgrading the old one.

The risk in renaming servers is from things (scripts, mapped drives, programs, DB connectors, etc) that reference the server by name.  The main risk is downtime, finding and fixing all of the references to the servers by their old name to their new name in locations that you were not aware of beforehand.  Depending on how your systems are setup, the data flow paths, and the end user's frenzied button clicking when it doesn't do what they want it to, you may end up in a situation where the data flow paths in your organisation are broken and data is lost due to it flowing from one system to nowhere.

Comment: Thanks BeowulfNode42, like you read my mind. It was sure going to disturb the db connector and some programs. As for shared drives which have scripts, I would have just updated them. But then its a BIG pain doing that for over 30 groups of users mapped to different network drives. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would hesitate renaming the servers for a number of reasons. Renaming a Domain Controller is simply a pain and not really worth the effort. Renaming anything else has a large potential for breaking stuff and annoying users. I do empathize - especially if you've inherited a lot of legacy stuff. Your best bet would be to set up DNS aliases for your gear and create a standard naming convention for the servers there. As upgrades happen or you find yourself with some significant free time you could phase the old names out from the servers themselves and then do the official swap in DNS as required.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. Your advice is good and I agree with you.